# why hudson failes the maven test build

Tags: maven-2, hudson, testng

I have one TestNG test in my project.
When I run it from command line with mvn **integration-test** it says:

> Running TestSuite
>   Testing  ...
>   Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.29 sec
>
> Results :
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> ### [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
>
> [INFO] Total time: 1.468s [INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 20 11:55:23 EEST
>
> ### 2011 [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/247M [INFO]

After I create a build in Hudson of type **Build a Maven 2/3 project (Legacy)**.
In goals I say **integration-test**.
In the end I do **Build now** and then what I see in Hudson console output is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building working 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default) @ working ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test (default) @ working ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\ybr\workspace\working\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Testing  ...
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.29 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[HUDSON] Recording test results
projectSucceeded m.no:working:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
projectFailed m.no:working:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
sessionEnded
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.253s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 20 11:56:27 EEST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.handleBuildError(BuilderCommon.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:146)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:124)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:283)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.model.RunMap$2.compare(RunMap.java:188)
```

Did anybody counter the problem and could write how it was solved.
Thank you in advance.

My POM is like that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>comcom.no</groupId>
<artifactId>working</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>working</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>


<build>

    <testSourceDirectory>src\test\java\m.no.working</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src\test\java\testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you append your pom.xml

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  If so, could you post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multiple threads?
There is a Fixed issue on Jenkins that was causing this failure regarding multi threads:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9183

Also, are you using Jenkins or Hudson?
Have you consider migrating to Jenkins?

Please refer to:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Upgrading+from+Hudson+to+Jenkins

That will solve many issues that are fixed on Jenkins.
Maybe you can try doing a POC for this and then propose moving Hudson into Jenkins.